# Mount or open disk I backed up with dd

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, mount, dd

I used the command `dd` in order to generate a full copy of a disk (a SD card). Now I'm trying to retrieve the information that was stored in there, but I don't know how to read the contents of the file. I used the comand `dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 of=/home/user/devmmcblk0.img bs=1M` to generate the file. The SD card is 16GB and so is the file, as ubuntu reports. The format of the file was fat32. I used the following command to install it: `mount -t vfat /home/user/devmmcblk0 /mnt` but it says `fstype incorrect, incorrect option, wrong superblock in /dev/loop0`. also I tried to install some linux in virtualbox and add the image file as secondary disk, but it won't let virtualbox mount it, giving the following error

```
Código Resultado: 
VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80BB0005)
Componente: 
Medium
Interfaz: 
IMedium {05f2bbb6-a3a6-4fb9-9b49-6d0dda7142ac}
Receptor: 
IVirtualBox {fafa4e17-1ee2-4905-a10e-fe7c18bf5554}
Receptor RC: 
VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80BB0001)
```

Any help in regards of recovering the information will be highly appreciated.

EDIT
I've been asked the output of several commands so I'll add them here for everyone to see

```
$ file -s devmmcblk0.img
devmmcblk0.img: x86 boot sector
```

```
$ mount -t vfat -o ro,loop /home/user/devmmcblk0 /mnt
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0
```

```
$ fdisk -lu devmmcblk0.img
Disk devmmcblk0.img: 16.0 GB, 16003891200 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1945 cylinders, total 31257600 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
    
Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
devmmcblk0.img1            8192    31257599    15624704    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Comment: Have you got another SD Card to write your disk image to?

Comment: Yes, but I'd prefer not if I can do it with an empty USB flash of 32 gigs. SD card has lots of things and I would avoid backing up and trying if possible. Is it stricly necessary that I `dd` the whole backup into the same type support I backed up?

Comment: any 32GB media should work so yes, write the image to a USB flash drive. of 32GB or above

Answer (score 0):

Update: please try with readonly option this time,

`sudo mount -t vfat -o ro,loop /home/user/devmmcblk0 /mnt`

Update2:

Seeing all the obstacles when dealing with the loopback device manually, perhaps you may want to try a higher level approach?  Please see if

`sudo testdisk devmmcblk0.img`

gives any good news

Update3:

It is likely to be an exfat formatted partition that requires `exfat-fuse` and `exfat-utils` for proper mount.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @hkdtam. The command you suggested gave the same error I stated in my question.

Comment: @c4tich thanks for your feedback, please try to see if you can mount it as readonly

Comment: no, still the same error message

Comment: @c4tich thanks again, I guess I may need more information to proceed, would you please show the output of `file -s devmmcblk0.img`? thanks.

Comment: thanks, the output is `devmmcblk0.img: x86 boot sector`

Comment: I followed these steps: selected `devmmcblk0`, chose `[intel]` partition,  chose `advanced` selected `devmmcblk0` again, chose `[boot]` at the bottom, it says that both boot sector and backup boot sectors are ok, and sectors are identical, chose `[rebuild FS]` at the bottom and it does something and goes back to the screen where I chose the last option, then there I choose`[repair FAT]`, which does not seem to do anything. After that I mounted the device, but the mountpoint was empty, with `ls -al` only showing `.` and `..`. Any ideas?

Comment: @c4tich this is indeed strange.  actually would you mind remastering the image from the SD card again?  Firstly, please try to show the print out of `sudo blkid` before and after you insert the SD card, thanks.

Comment: the output shows information about my disk devices. I think you are more interested in this one, the only one that doesn't appear before inserting SD card but it does appear after inserting it: `/dev/mmcblk0p1: UUID="9016-4EF8" TYPE="vfat"`

Comment: @c4tich Thanks.  Please also compare the output of `sudo fdisk -l` with and without the SD card.  After that let's do a readonly mount test then. Please insert the SD card again and issue `sudo mount -t vfat -o ro /dev/mmcblk0p1 /mnt` and after that do a `ls -l /mnt` to see if the expect contents are there.  Once it is done just dismount the SD card with `sudo umount /mnt`

Answer (score 0):

You should mount the partition, it starts with an offset inside your file.

```
sudo mount -o offset=$((512*8192)),ro,loop -t vfat /home/user/devmmcblk0.img /mnt
```

Notes:

- `loop` may not be necessary.
- `512` is sector size as reported by `fdisk`.
- `8192` is the start sector.

Your image covers whole SD card; it's similar to (e.g.) `/dev/sdb`. If it was SD card, then there would be `/dev/sdb1` available to mount. Mounting `sdb1` would be mounting `sdb` with appropriate offset automagically. With image file there is no such magic – you have no special `devmmcblk0.img1`. It is possible to create such a file by hand, yet cumbersome and not really necessary (edit: `kpartx` in KevinB's answer does that). The easiest way is to pass the right offset to `mount` command.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, the output of `mount` was `mount: /dev/loop0: can't read superblock`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

kpartx is also an option. From a website on the internet:

```
# kpartx -l gothbook.img
loop1p1 : 0 512000 /dev/loop1 63
loop1p2 : 0 512000 /dev/loop1 512063
loop1p3 : 0 45056000 /dev/loop1 1024063
loop1p5 : 0 8388608 /dev/loop1 46090548
loop1p6 : 0 39070017 /dev/loop1 54492543
loop1p7 : 0 62733762 /dev/loop1 93562623
```

I can see from the output of kpartx that my drive image contains 6 partitions.  I can see their starting offsets.  The first column tells me the names of the device files that will be created if I choose to add these device partitions.  Lets add them now.

```
# kpartx -a -v gothbook.img
add map loop1p1 (253:6): 0 512000 linear /dev/loop1 63
add map loop1p2 (253:7): 0 512000 linear /dev/loop1 512063
add map loop1p3 (253:8): 0 45056000 linear /dev/loop1 1024063
add map loop1p5 (253:9): 0 8388608 linear /dev/loop1 46090548
add map loop1p6 (253:10): 0 39070017 linear /dev/loop1 54492543
add map loop1p7 (253:11): 0 62733762 linear /dev/loop1 93562623

# ls -l /dev/mapper
total 0
crw-rw---- 1 root root  10, 62 2010-06-15 17:40 control
brw-rw-r-- 1 neil neil 253,  6 2010-08-16 00:28 loop1p1
brw-rw-r-- 1 neil neil 253,  7 2010-08-16 00:28 loop1p2
brw-rw-r-- 1 neil neil 253,  8 2010-08-16 00:28 loop1p3
brw-rw-r-- 1 neil neil 253,  9 2010-08-16 00:28 loop1p5
brw-rw-r-- 1 neil neil 253, 10 2010-08-16 00:28 loop1p6
brw-rw-r-- 1 neil neil 253, 11 2010-08-16 00:28 loop1p7
```

The preceeding command added six device map files to /dev/mapper.  Each of these device files corresponds to a partition from that hard drive image.  We can now use these device files to mount these partitions and access any files they contain.
I want to mount the fifth partition (/dev/mapper/loop1p6) and have a look at its files.

```
# mkdir /mnt/sysimage
# mount /dev/mapper/loop1p6 /mnt/sysimage
# ls /mnt/sysimage
bin    dev   initrd.img      lost+found  opt   sbin     sys  var
boot   etc   initrd.img.old  media       proc  selinux  tmp  vmlinuz
cdrom  home  lib             mnt         root  srv      usr  vmlinuz.old
```

After mounting the device file, you can access the files contained on that partition.  When you are done, don’t forget to umount the partition and disconnect the device map files using kpartx.

`# umount /mnt/sysimage
# kpartx -d -v gothbook.img`

Comment: thanks for your answer. `mount` command gives as output the following: `mount: /dev/mapper/loop0p1: can't read superblock`. Can you help me out further on this issue?

Comment: What is the output of `file -s /dev/mapper/loop0p1`? Invoke with `sudo` if necessary.

Comment: `/dev/mapper/loop0p1: ERROR: cannot open `/dev/mapper/loop0p1' (No such file or directory)`. Sorry for the delay.